# Relationships, get products where relationship table belongs to the user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So I have 2 tables products, and purchases, I am trying to get the purchases that belong to the owner of the product. Anyone can purchases, but only the user owns the product

I have my tables like so:

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->text('description');
    $table->string('category');
    $table->string('auction_type');
    $table->string('allow_offers');
    $table->string('condition');
    $table->integer('quantity');
    $table->integer('auctionlength');
    $table->decimal('buyitnow_price');
    $table->decimal('auction_price');
    $table->string('shipping');
    $table->decimal('shipping_cost');
    $table->integer('shipping_time');
    $table->string('international_shipping');
    $table->string('location');
    $table->string('allow_returns');
    $table->date('enddate');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});
```

**Purchases table**

```
Schema::create('purchases', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id');
    $table->integer('product_id');
    $table->decimal('amount');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('address');
    $table->string('city');
    $table->string('state');
    $table->string('country');
    $table->string('postal');
    $table->string('email');
    $table->string('status');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});
```

I have tried the following but this still seems to get rows:

```
dd(Product::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->with('purchases')->get());
```

**Purchases model**

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Market\Product');
}
```

**Product model**

```
public function purchases()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Market\Purchases');    
}
```

My two models are `Purchases` and `Products`, without raw query, how can I get the purchase of products that belongs to `user_id`?

Comment: I really recommend you to use the documentation before asking any question, you have to understand how Laravel works, like Eloquent, and then do your model/DB, and then asks us. It is really hard to help some that doesn't write well and even doesn't know anything about the system he/she is using...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Some suggestions describe a solution where we fetch the products along with each of their purchases. This can work, but we need to extract the purchases from each product into one collection:

```
$purchases = Product::with('purchases')
    ->where('user_id', $ownerId)
    ->get()
    ->pluck('purchases')
    ->flatten();
```

Here's a more performant approach—we can directly fetch purchases for a product owned by a particular user:

```
$purchases = Purchase::with('product') 
    ->whereHas('product', function ($query) use ($ownerId) { 
        $query->where('user_id', $ownerId);
    })
    ->get();
```

We can remove `with('product')` from the query above if we don't need to use any data stored on the product for each purchase.

Comment: I don't get it. I already answered this, and better, with Eloquent relationships, no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: You clearly never. Look what his does, and compare yours... this does the correct thing of selecting ALL purchases that belong to ALL my products..

Comment: Hi @matiaslauriti, I hope I can help clarify. Both solutions in this answer *do use* Eloquent relations...my code above won't work without them. The question asks for a way to fetch a *one-dimensional set* of `Purchase` records for the specified criteria, so I wrote examples that use the relationships from the question to produce the requested result set. Your answer contains *part* of the solution and deserves a +1...it would work if `user_id` is the same on both tables, but `user_id` on `purchases` is the user who bought a product, not the product owner, so `$user->purchases` won't work.

Comment: @matiaslauriti It's an easy detail to miss, and I almost made the same mistake. Let me know if this sounds reasonable. If this makes sense, please consider changing your vote.

Answer (score 1):

Your User model must have a `hasMany` relation, at least with `Purchases` (because here you are trying to get that), the best would be with both models, like this

```php
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Products::class);
}

public function purchases()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Purchases::class);
}
```

To get the purchases, you can do

```php
$user->purchases;
```

Assuming `$user` already has a `User` model (with data), when you call the relation as a property (not a method) you will get a `Collection` (because is a `hasMany` relation).

I am doing all of this by memory.

So you can then access, let say, the first purchase returned

```php
$purchases = $user->purchases;

$purchases->first()->name;
```

---

**EDIT**: So you are trying to get all purchases made on a product.
You will have to define a relation on `Products` model.

So you need to access `Products` model, do the relation I've done to get `Purchases`

```php
public function purchases()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Purchases::class);
}
```

And then, you have access to all the purchases done on that product.

Comment: That will only get the user's purchases, and the products.. I am trying to get the purchases made by other user's that bought my product

Comment: @randommman I have updated my answer. It is really important that you understand how relation works, because it is one of the best things about Eloquent.

Comment: Is that possible for every item i own to get every purchase?

Comment: If I understood your question, yes. With this you will get all purchases that the column `product_id` is equal to the current `Product` id model you are using.

Comment: That only get the specific items purchases, not every purchase that belongs to a product I own

Comment: Can you make it clear ? Are you trying to get all items of a single purchase ? Are you trying to get all the purchases of an item ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one buddy :)

purchases model

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product:class ,'product_id', 'id');
}
```

product model

```
public function purchases()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Purchases::class,'id', 'product_id');    
}
```